# CF9 ORM Populating an entity with an object

Tags: orm, coldfusion

I am using Model-Glue/Coldspring for a new application and I thought I would throw CF9 ORM into the mix.

The only issue I am having right now is with populating an entity with an object. More or less the code below verifies that only one username can exist. There is some other logic that is not displayed.

My first thought was to using something like this:

`var entity = entityload('UserAccount' ,{UserName=arguments.UserAccount.getUserName()},"true")`

`entity = arguments.UserAccount;`

How ever this does not work the way that I expected. Is it even possible to populate an entity with an object or do I need to use the setters?

Comment: Does not work the way that you expected?  What do you expect really?

Comment: I was expecting the entity to be populated with the values from the object.

Comment: `UserAccount` should be your entity.  Just set `persistent=true` on it.  Why do you need to populate entity with `UserAccount`?

Comment: arguments.UserAccount is a value object passed in from Flex

Comment: I think it'd be best to write your init() or populate() to populate your CF entity from your Flex VO.

Comment: but I have no exp with doing Flex w/ CF, maybe there's an easier way...

Comment: Your example wouldn't work because you are overwriting the "entity" var with your passed object on the second line. It may have loaded, but you've immediately overwritten it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it even possible to populate an entity with an object or do I need to use the setters?

If you mean "Is it possible to <strike>create</strike> load an ORM Entity from an instance of that persistent CFC that already exists and has properties set?", then yes you can using `EntityLoadByExample( object,[unique] )`

```
entity = EntityLoadByExample( arguments.userAccount,true );
```

This assumes the userAccount CFC has been defined as persistent, and its username value has been set before being passed in (which seems to be the case in your situation).

Bear in mind that if any other properties have been set in the object you are passing, including empty strings, they will be used as filters to load the entity, so if they do not exactly match a record in your database, nothing will be loaded.

Comment: This will only work for previously persisted entities. Henry's answer is best for dealing with new, unsaved objects.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for.  If you have...

```
component persistent="true" entityName="Foo" 
{
  property a;
  property b;
}
```

You can pass a struct in the 2nd param to init the entity (added in CF9.0.1 I believe)

```
EntityNew("Foo", {a="1",b="2"});
```

To populate Foo with another object, you can use the Memento pattern, and implement a `GetMemento()` function to your object that returns a struct of all its properties.

```
EntityNew("Foo", bar.getMemento());
```

However, CF does NOT call your custom setters!  If you want to set them using setters, you may add calls to the setters in your `init()` constructor, or use your MVC framework of choice to populate the bean.  In Model-Glue, it is `makeEventBean()`.

**Update:** Or... Here's  hack...

```
EntityNew("Foo", DeserializeJSON(SerializeJSON(valueObject)));
```

Use this at your own risk.  JSON might do weird things to your numbers and the 'yes','no','true','false' strings.  :)